# how to access tableviewcell using tableview instance

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I am trying to change the particular tableview cell property through tableview instance.

In Objective c we can do that using the following code

```
id cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The equivalent way of accessing in Xamarin seems impossible.

I know I can invoke reloaddata method on tableview instance and do the changes in getcell but I don't want to do like that I want to directly edit instead of triggering a reloaddata.

Comment: `var cell = aTableViewInstance.CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromIndex(1));`

Comment: I can access cell's elements such as label or button and edit the behaviour right

Comment: Please post it as answer ...I will accept it

Comment: `cell` in my example is a `UITableViewCell`, so cast it to your custom cell class and everything in that cell would be available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain a `UITableViewCell` from a `UITableView` from "some" index via:

```
var cell = aTableViewInstance.CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromIndex(1));
```

Cast `cell` to your custom `UITableViewCell` type if needed to access any additional method/properties that you might have added.

> CellAt(NSIndexPath) : UITableViewCell
>
> Returns the table cell at the specified index path.

- https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UITableView/

Comment: Thanks ! Congratulations on your 1000th answer which is this one ! :)

Comment: How did you manage to contribute so much in shorter period of time ? How may hours do you spend everyday ? Please open up on your success story ...How did you do that ? What is it like to be SushiHangover in a day ?